# Remove space at the end of a string using strip() or rstrip() in python

Tags: python, strip

My goal is to read a csv file and then print the 10 items with One Single Space between them. Following are the tasks to do that:

1. If the string has more than one word than add "Double quotes" around it.

The problem i am facing is that if it is a single string but with white space at the end, i am supposed to remove it.

I tried strip and rstrip in python, but it doesnt seem to work.

Following is the code for it:

```
with open(accidents_csv, mode='r', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if count <=10:
            new_row = [beautify_columns(item) for item in row]
            print(' '.join(new_row))
            count +=1
def beautify_columns(col):
    col.strip()
    if(' ' in col):
        col = f'"{col}"'
    return col
```

The following image shows the current behavior of the code without removing the trailing spaces.
[image: The image shows the current behavior of the code without removing the trailing spaces.]

Kindly advise me how to remove spaces at the end of a string

Comment: can you give some inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the result of strip(), i.e.

```
col = col.strip()
```

Only other thing to note is that `strip()` will remove whitespace (i.e. not just space characters) at beginning as well as end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Partially unrelated, but a `csv.writer` could natively meet your other requirements, because it will automatically quote fields containing a separator:

```
with open(accidents_csv, mode='r', encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
    csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=" ")
    for count, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        new_row = [item.strip() for item in row]
        csv_writer.writerow(new_row)
        if count >= 9: break
```

As said by @barny, `strip()` will remove all whitespace characters, including `"\r"` or `"\t"`. Use `strip(' ')` if you want to only remove space characters.